# Information about the date of last change of the string in Transifex

Tags: feature-request, localization, transifex

Currently there is no information about the date, when the string was added/changed in Transifex. (The Localization Platform used by Stack Exchange for the localized sites)

We can filter by date and using method of exclusion detect the exact date.

But would be great if this info will be added.